# Highstock tooltip 'a tag' doesn't get rendered

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to add anchor tag in tooltip of highstock flags.

I am facing couple of problems with that:

1. Anchor tags are not displayed in tooltip.
2. When I try to hover over the tooltip, the tooltip disappears.

My code looks like:

```js
$.getJSON('https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/usdeur.json', function (data) {

  var year = new Date(data[data.length - 1][0]).getFullYear(); // Get year of last data point

  // Create the chart
  Highcharts.stockChart('container', {


    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 4
    },

    title: {
      text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Exchange rate'
      }
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'USD to EUR',
      data: data,
      id: 'dataseries',
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 4
      }
    },{
      type: 'flags',
      data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(year, 11, 1),
        title: 'B',
        text: 'make me clickable'
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(year, 11, 1),
        title: 'B',
        text: '<a>make me clickable</a>'
      }],
      shape: 'circlepin',
      onSeries: 'dataseries',
      width: 16,
      tooltip: {                          
                          pointFormat: '<a href="#">{point.text}</a>'
                      }       ,
      style:{
        border:'1px solid green'
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `useHTML` to `true` for the tooltip. To easier hover on tooltip, increase `hideDelay` value and disable `stickyTracking` on series:

```
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        hideDelay: 5000
    }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ncrgwvzu/

API:

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.stickyTracking

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.useHTML